# Subprocess.call and --stdout

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess, stdout, espeak

```
subprocess.call(["espeak", "-s 5 -ven", "where are you", "--stdout", 'shell=True', "aplay"])
```

The output of this will just be a massive output of special characters, and not the audio from the espeak. When i type this:

```
subprocess.call(["espeak", "-s 5 -ven", "where are you", 'shell=True', "aplay"])
```

then the audio is heard, but there are some problems with the speech being slow sometimes, together with output of messages below:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
```

Can someone explain what --stdout means here? And why is it causing the error as mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [espeak documentation](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/commands.html):

> --stdout
>
> Writes the speech output to stdout as it is produced, rather than speaking it. 
>   The data starts with a WAV file header which
>   indicates the sample rate and format of the data. The length field is
>   set to zero because the length of the data is unknown when the header
>   is produced.

For `jack server is not running or cannot be started` error check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=20923) for solution:

> Do you have installed the alsa package (type 'alsa' and the tab key
>   twice, you should see some commands beginning with alsa..)? If it
>   isn't installed, do that with
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install alsa-tools alsa-utils
> ```

Anyway this error shouldn't prevent `espeak` from working. You can  remove it by redirecting `stderr` to `/dev/null` as follows:

```
FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
retcode = subprocess.call(["espeak", "-s 5", "-ven", "where are you", "aplay"], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Also please note that you're using `shell=True` as one of the arguments to `espeak`, which should be actually argument of `call` method itself.
Just remove it.

Comment: ALSA is already there. Adding  2>/dev/null still doesn't do the trick. Is still the same.

Comment: @sam What do you mean still the same? error "jack server is not running or cannot be started" ? or something else?

Comment: I type this: `subprocess.call(["espeak", "-s 5 -ven", "where are you", "2>/dev/null", 'shell=True', "aplay"])`    and it comes out 
`jack server is not running or cannot be started`

Comment: @sam do you have `jackd` installed? `sudo apt-get install jackd`

Comment: @sam btw, adding "2>/dev/null" isn't the right way to cause `call` method redirect stderr to `/dev/null`. Please see how to do it right in my answer.

Comment: `FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')`  `retcode = subprocess.call(["espeak", "-s 5", "-ven", "where are you", "aplay"], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`  This method worked. But there is one problem now. How do i put a variable to replace the "where are you"? `retcode = subprocess.call(["espeak", "-s 5", "-ven", str(variable_name) "aplay"], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` causes invalid syntax.

Comment: Looks like you forgot `,` after `str (digit)`